# Accessing state outside a component with react-redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a large react-redux based application in development. I'd like to add some utility functions to a js script that does not contain a react component to "connect" to. How do I access the state in react-redux without a component? Neither `mapStateToProps` nor `mapDispatchToProps` are available - do I need to export the state object from the top-level index.js file? Seems dangerous.

Suggestions welcome!

JB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460949/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-redux-store-outside-a-react-component

Comment: @Jaked222 - I don't want to export or import the store (although this is all client side so I could). Also, per Abramov's suggestion linked from that page, I was considering simply creating a component with an empty render() method but was looking for a better solution...

Comment: What is "connect" mean in your context? You should try refs.

Comment: `import { connect } from 'react-redux';`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No really graceful way to do it. Long argument list it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround way:**
*Import your store inside the scope of your utility functions.*

Importing the store (which you would have created while setting up your app) will provide ***dispatch*** and ***getState*** methods using which you can get access to your state vars.

**src/store.js**

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducers from './reducers';

var middleware = [ReduxThunk];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  middleware = [...middleware, logger];
}

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(createStore);

export default createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
```

**helper.js**

```
import store from "./store"
const { var1, var2 } = store.getState();
```

Answer (score -1):

The phrasing of your question is just a bit odd.  If you're asking about accessing the store in utility functions that aren't related to any components, then you *aren't* using React-Redux to do so :)

In this case, you would either import the store directly into those utility function modules, or call the functions from some scope that *does* have access to store capabilities (such as a thunk action creator that was dispatched from a connected component).

There's a related [Redux FAQ entry on why you should generally prefer to not import the store directly](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html#store-setup-multiple-stores).

Comment: Yeah I don't want to import the store directly as I think that's a bad idea. I am indeed calling the functions and sending them data from store-aware components but I wanted to avoid all that parameter passing if possible...