# How do I pass a token to Apollo requests?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to pass a token from my redux store to all of my Apollo requests.  I know you can forward the [cookies](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/auth.html)

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  },
});
```

but I want to add it to the header.

```
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {};  // Create the header object if needed.
    }
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    req.options.headers.authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;
    next();
  }
}]);
```

but how do I get the `token` out of the store.  Getting it out of `localStorage` is not an option, because my app is server side rendered, so I don't have acces to `localStorage` at all times.  I need to be able to access the Redux store.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can export your store and import where you setup your Networkinterface. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460949/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-redux-store-outside-a-react-component#answer-41172768).