# React Native - Redux - How can I call an action from a non-component?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I want to update the store with an action fired from a function in a helper class.

How can I bind and fire that action if my class is not a component?

A solution I have seen is to use a renderless component which returns `null` in its `render()` function. That way you can bind your actions to it. But this seems like a hackey solution and it would cause an unpleasant refactor of my helper class.

Comment: You could import the store directly, and pass your action to its `dispatch` method.

Comment: @djfdev Would that ensure that that store is the one the rest of the app is using and not a copy or something else?

Comment: Correct. Here's a possible duplicate of your question with a lot of discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460949/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-redux-store-outside-a-react-component