# Redux store accessed outside of a component returns initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I would like to know if what I'm trying to achieve is doable and if yes, then I would like to find out what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm using a react-native-threads library to create a separate "thread". Inside there should be some setInterval function that checks the current state of the app, say every 20 seconds. 
Now inside that thread, I was trying to do something similar to what was described in the best answer for this question: 
[What is the best way to access redux store outside a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460949/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-redux-store-outside-a-react-component)
However, I'm using redux-persist so I don't have a plain 'store' variable inside the store config file. 
Code for store setup:

```
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    appState: appStateReducer,
    entries: entriesReducer,
    listHelper: listHelperReducer,
    authenticate: authenticateReducer
})

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
    blacklist: [ 'appState' , 'listHelper'],
    whitelist: ['authenticate' , 'entries']

}
const pr = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
const configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(pr,  devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true, hostname: 'localhost', port: 8082 }))

    const persistor = persistStore(store)
    return { persistor, store }
}
export default configureStore
```

I have tried importing the configureStore from that file and accessing the state like this inside the index.thread.js:

```
console.tron.log(configureStore().store.getState());
```

However, this is returning the initial state. I need the current state, after rehydration.
Has anyone tried to solve a similar issue? I will be very grateful for any hints. Thank you.

Edit: Here is the index.js file where the configureStore is called.

```
const store = configureStore();
const RNRedux = () => (
  <Provider store={store.store}>
    <PersistGate loading={<LoadingScreen />} persistor={store.persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);


AppRegistry.registerComponent("ProjectName", () => RNRedux);
```

Comment: You are creating a new store every time you call `configureStore()`, hence the default values `configureStore()`.

Comment: Yeah I assumed this. How can I access the actual store that has already been created? The configureStore() is called inside my index.js but I cannot put any export there without crashing the app

Comment: Maybe instead of exporting a function called `configureStore` you can run the code insight that function directly on the module level and export `store` and `persistor` directly.

Comment: @AnnieHill Hi did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the createStore in your store file and export it from there.

```
const pr = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(pr,  devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true, hostname: 'localhost', port: 8082 }))
const configureStore = () => {
    const persistor = persistStore(store)
    return { persistor, store }
}

export default configureStore
```

Now you can use the store like below.

```
console.tron.log(configureStore.store.getState());
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I do it like you have described above I'm getting this error: 
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_configureStore2.default.configureStore.store)
Then, if I call it like this: configureStore().store.getState() it returns initial state again.
Or if I import it like this: {configureStore} im getting same error as mentioned above but sligtly different (_configureStore.configureStore.store)

Comment: I have tried it like this:
`const pr = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
    export const store = createStore(pr,  devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true, 
        hostname: 'localhost', port: 8082 }))
    export const persistor = persistStore(store, null, () => {
        console.log('state', store.getState());
  });`

But I was still getting a new instance of the store

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my issue was circular dependencies between files. That left some variables uninitialised so I would recommend double checking that.