# Sharing a single store between two or more react applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How can I share a redux store between two or more applications on the same page? (assuming because of the requirements, it's not possible to put the two apps under the same components tree).

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store.js';
import App1 from './App1.js';
import App2 from './App2.js';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App1 />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#app-1')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App2 />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#app-2')
);
```

Comment: few possible solutions might be found while looking for "redux micro fronted". Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853824/how-to-share-redux-store-in-micro-frontend-architecture but I'm not sure if that's 100% relevant, so not making an official answer

Comment: @skyboyer thank you. I'm checking.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost identical requirements. I need to render completely separate React roots with ReactDOM. But I also need to share state between them. Due to limitations from the requirements I don't have the ability to have a centralized top-level mount which would allow me to use context/props to do this. The only approach I found that worked was to use event-based state orchestration: (my use case was one-way, but this could easily be used for two-way orchestration)

Main.jsx

```
...
ReactDOM.render(<App1 />, document.querySelector('#app-1'));

ReactDOM.render(<App2 />, document.querySelector('#app-2'));
...
```

App1.jsx (emitter pattern)

```
...
const [myCustomState, setMyCustomState] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCustomState', { detail: myCustomState }));
}, [myCustomState]);
...
```

App2.jsx (subscriber pattern)

```
...
const [myCustomState, setMyCustomState] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const updateMyCustomState = ({ detail }) => setMyCustomState(detail);

  document.addEventListener(`myCustomState`, updateMyCustomState);

  return () => document.removeEventListener(`myCustomState`, updateMyCustomState);
}, [setMyCustomState]);
...
```