# How to export Axios.create in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I have this working:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'sample',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  transformRequest: [
    (data) => {
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
  ],
});
```

but the problem is once I edited to be like this:

```
const API = () => {
 const token = 'sample'

  const api: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    transformRequest: [
      (data) => {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      },
    ],
    transformResponse: [
      (data) => {
        return JSON.parse(data);
      },
    ],
  });

  return api;
};

export default API;
```

I want it to be an arrow function so I can access the token inside the function.

The problem is once I start to import the arrow function it will create an error not reading POST method

```
import API from 'apis';

API.post
```

Is there a way to implement it like an arrow function but will not lose the type definitions or create an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't loose any type definitions, but you're not using your import as a function.

If you write `API().post` it will work.

I would suggest doing the following:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  transformRequest: [
    (data) => {
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
  ],
  transformResponse: [
    (data) => {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    },
  ],
});

import store from '../store'

const listener = () => {
  const token = store.getState().token
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
}

store.subscribe(listener)

export default api;
```

You can access the token here as well.

Comment: the problem is there a way to access the store using useselector or connect in redux?

Comment: Please refer to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38480550/11098471, since js objects are passed by reference, you can simply edit properties in your instance. I'll update my example to make this possible

Answer (score 1):

Just because this is the question you find when you look for my problem, if you use `require` to import axios, to use the correct type definition you'll have to import it like that:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default
axios.create(...) // No error
```

This would give an error:

```
const axios = require('axios')
axios.create(...) // Error
```