# How to access the Redux store outside of a component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am beginning with Redux and I always used it in components with connect() and mapStateToProps(), but now I want to call my API with setInterval() every x time to check if the server has new data not stored in the Redux store, and substitute it.

My approach was to create a function that reads the store and update it like that:

```
import { store } from './dir/dir/store.js'

const refresher = async () => {

    const state = store.getState();

    // Call API, compare 'state.calendar' with calendar from server
    // Call store.dispatch() if they are different, then update Redux store

}

export default refresher
```

My questions are:

- Is this a good practise to use Redux?
- Is there a better approach to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your data needs to be accessed everywhere in your app ?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460949/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-redux-store-outside-a-react-component

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi - It is everywhere but the components that use the store are already working, I just need to modify the store outside a component.

Comment: @krimo - Thanks, I followed that example in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38480550/9616888) - I think that is what I needed, but not so sure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to export the store and use within a vanilla js/ts file.

#### Example Redux Store

Make sure to `export` the `store` that you create

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { slice } from "../features/counterSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: slice.reducer
  }
});
```

#### Usage in Non-Component Code:

You can then `import` the created `store` in any other code

```
import { store } from "../App/store";
import { slice as counterSlice } from "../features/counterSlice";

export function getCount(): number {
  const state = store.getState();
  return state.counter.value;
}

export function incrementCount() {
  store.dispatch(counterSlice.actions.increment());
}
```

#### Traditional Usage in Functional Component

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../App/store";
import { slice as counterSlice } from "../features/counterSlice";

export function Clicker() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const count = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value);
  const dispatchIncrement = () => dispatch(counterSlice.actions.increment())
  // ...
```

### Example Slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState: { value: 0 },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    }
  }
});
```

#### [Demo in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/export-redux-store-8djyj)

**Note**: You cannot use this option with Server Side Rendering.  If you need to support SSR, you can [use middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/361) to listen to dispatched actions and handle elsewhere.

### Further Reading

- [What is the best way to access redux store outside a react component? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38460949/1366033)
- [Access the Redux Store Outside a React Component | Blog](https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/)
- [How can I access the store in non react components? | Github Issues](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/361)

Comment: But if you use store as context in your app via redux provider, it brings you to circular dependency. How deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can access the store and action out side any component like index.js file in react-native.

```
import {updateLocationAlertItem} from './src/store/actions/locationAlertAction';
import {store} from './src/store/index';

store.subscribe(listener);

function listener() {
    state = store.getState().locationAlertReducer;
}


store.dispatch(
   updateLocationAlertItem({
        index: index,
         is_in_radius: true,
         is_notification: true,
         arrival_time: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'),
         exit_time: item.exit_time,
   }),
);
```